# Rust generic function accepting both primitive and rug integers

Tags: rust, biginteger, trait-bounds

I'm trying to write a generic function that operates on integers, which can accept either primitive integers or multiprecision ones (via `rug`). The tricky bit is that references to rug `Integer`s have lazy arithmetic operations, that [return incomplete types until cast into an integer](https://docs.rs/rug/latest/rug/#incomplete-computation-values). So I thought something like the following would work, but I can't seem to get the lifetime setting correct (and rust-analyzer is not being super verbose in helping):

```
use rug::Integer;
use std::ops::Mul;

fn mymul<T, S>(x: &T, y: &T) -> T
where
    T: 'static + From<S>,
    for<'a> &'a T: Mul<&'a T, Output = S>,
{
    T::from(x * y)
}

fn main() {
    let x: u64 = 3847381;
    let y: u64 = 28478195;
    let rug_x = Integer::from(x);
    let rug_y = Integer::from(y);
    println!("{} == {:?}", mymul(&x, &y), mymul(&rug_x, &rug_y));
}
```

with error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:22:43
   |
22 |     println!("{} == {:?}", mymul(&x, &y), mymul(&rug_x, &rug_y));
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected struct `integer::arith::MulIncomplete<'a>`
              found struct `integer::arith::MulIncomplete<'_>`
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
  --> src/main.rs:12:31
   |
12 |     for<'a> &'a T: Mul<&'a T, Output = S>,
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any idea how to do this sort of thing correctly?

Comment: Please edit in the full error message.

Comment: Nit: generally, you should not bound on `From` but on `Into`.

Comment: Why did you introduce the bound `T: 'static`?

Comment: The compiler suggested it at some point in the evolution of this code, but your solution is clearly the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The right way to specify this function with HRTB is:

```rust
fn mymul<T>(x: &T, y: &T) -> T
where
    for<'a> &'a T: Mul<&'a T>,
    for<'a> <&'a T as Mul<&'a T>>::Output: Into<T>,
{
    (x * y).into()
}
```